# Why doesn't this regex grab individual matches for each <li>?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to capture anything and everything that can happen between an opening and closing li tag using the following regex:

```
/<li[\w\s\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\-\_\+\=\~\`\.\,\:\;\"\/\–\?\{\}\[\]\(\)\<\>\ \|\'\\]+<\/li>/g
```

[I have created the regex here on regex 101.](https://regex101.com/r/OTcwF6/1)

I can't figure out why it's not grabbing individual li elements instead of all text between the first and last li.  I'm not terribly familiar with the structure of regexes so I'm not sure what I need to research to capture all the attributes, special characters, etc that might show and still terminate the individual matches on the closing `</li>` tag.

UPDATE:
[New Regex101 demo that better reflects the examples I'm trying to capture](https://regex101.com/r/OTcwF6/7) (even my original regex fails some of them)

Comment: matching HTML with reg exp is a BAD idea.

Comment: appreciated, no alternative in this case however.  Complex context and not relevant to the question

Comment: So you can not parse it with a fragment and read it?

Comment: converting html to markdown with no access to libs, ES5 only, etc.  hundreds of thousands of DIRTY DIRTY inputs and I've finally reached this point inches from the finish line only to find this regex laughing at me. :)

Comment: How about: https://regex101.com/r/OTcwF6/2

Comment: Problem is a reg exp would not be able to handle `<li><ul><li></li></ul></li>` hopefully you have no nested lists.

Comment: @Toto looks promising!  https://regex101.com/r/OTcwF6/4 Testing and if it works, please set in answer form and I'll mark it.

Comment: @Shane If you're doing this from inside the browser, you could add your HTML document to the page, allow the browser to parse it, then traverse (or `document.getElementsByTagName`) the DOM it generates. Far less error-prone, far richer searching abilities.

Comment: @jpaugh - agreed.  This will be happening inside a google scripts environment among others, so it will need to work in circumstances where the browser and other js libs aren't available

Comment: @Shane Even in an ideal environment, converting between HTML and markdown can be tricky, since both languages have ambiguities and gotchas.  Whatever solution you come to, you'll need a high tolerance for errors, especially by relying on regexes. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use:

```
<li[^>]*>(.*?)<\/li>
```

Where:

- `[^>]*` means any character that is not `>`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OTcwF6/2)

Comment: Works in my app as well (where I'm inserting the tag name dynamically)

Comment: One thing to note for anyone trying this later would be to add the /gs flag if you want this to work across multiple lines

Answer (score 1):

Just change `+` to `+?` so that it becomes "lazy" to match as few characters as possible

```
<li[\w\s\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\-\_\+\=\~\`\.\,\:\;\"\/\–\?\{\}\[\]\(\)\<\>\ \|\'\\]+?<\/li>
                                                                   added this ^
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/OTcwF6/3

Also, you might want to put the stuff between the html tags in a group `<li([...]+?)<\/li>` so that you can get that stuff separate from the tags themselves.  I don't know what your use case is, but this seems like it might be something you'll need.

---

**Edit** ok, how about just this then.  the `.` matches any character, so `.*?` means "match anything as few times as possible or nothing at all".  This is *much* simpler and seems to match everything needed for your complex example

```
<li.*?>(.+?)<\/li>
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/OTcwF6/8

Comment: fails in some cases I didn't include originally, sorry about that: eg. https://regex101.com/r/OTcwF6/6

Comment: This seems to work in my app as well, chips fell to Toto just off the timing of his comment.  Hard to mark "one" answer as correct with regex's.

Answer (score 0):

Edit due to comment:

https://regex101.com/r/nR8mbC/4

```
(<li.*?>)(.*)(<\/li>)
```

Comment: Why do you make the `i` optional in `<li?` and why do you escape `<` and `>`?